# Getting AuthFailure Error when using StringRequest using Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am sending Volley StringRequest as follows

```
    StringRequest getRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, myUrl,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        if (response!=null)
                        {
                           //do some work
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.d("error",e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("error",error.toString());
                }
            }
    ) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            String token = "",cookie="";
            token = getSharedPreferences(getResources().
                    getString(R.string.pref_login_data), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                    .getString("login_token","");
            cookie = "token="+token+";";
            Map<String, String>  param = new HashMap<String, String>();
            param.put("api-key", myAPIKey);
            param.put("Cookie", cookie);
            return param;
        }
    };
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(getRequest);
```

Each time onErrorResponse called and it gives AuthFailure Error

but when I hit same url with same headers in postman, it works and json string is returned
the screenshot of postman is as follows:

[image: postman response]

I am struggling to solve this issue for more than 3 days, any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

only change Request.Method.GET to Request.Method.POST.

Because you are sending the parameters by POST method, but you have used the Get method!

Comment: M.ghorbani this is GET request I want, not a POST request, and i am sending headers not parameters. I think parameters are sent by overriding getParams()